# SQL to find date intervals

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with time periods like (no overlap in time periods):

```
start_date        end_date
-----------------------------
12-aug-14         12-nov-14
12-jan-15         12-apr-15
12-jun-15         12-aug-15
... 5 more
```

I'm trying to find the in between time periods - something like:

```
12-nov-14         12-jan-15
12-apr-15         12-jun-15
...
```

However, my queries are giving all time period differences like:

```
12-nov-14         12-jan-15
12-nov-14         12-jun-15
```

My query was:

```
select 
    l1.end_date, l2.start_date 
from 
    lease l1, lease l2 
where 
    l1.place_no = 'P1' and l2.place_no = 'P1' 
    and l2.start_date > l1.end_date 
order by 
    l1.end_date asc;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` your table, use `rownum` and then `join` them:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       ROWNUM AS RN
FROM ( SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY 1,2)
)
SELECT T1.END_DATE, T2.START_DATE
FROM CTE T1 JOIN CTE T2 ON T2.RN=T1.RN+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lead()`.  That is what the function is designed for:

```
select l.*,
       lead(start_date) over (partition by place_no order by start_date) as next_start_date,
       (lead(start_date) over (partition by place_no order by start_date) as next_start_date - end_date) as gap
from lease l
where l1.place_no = 'P1';
```

There is no need for a `join` or even for subqueries -- unless you want to eliminate the additional row that has a NULL value because there is no next value.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tricky.  You are currently creating a cartesian, which is close, after you create your cartesian, use a group-by to limit it back down to just the start-rows, and the minimum end-rows:

```
select
 l1.end_date,
 min(l2.start_date)
from 
    lease l1 
    inner join lease l2 ON
        l1.place_no = l2.place_no and
        l2.start_date >= l1 end_date
where 
    l1.place_no = 'P1'
group by
    l1.start_date
having
    l2.start_date != l1.end_date
```

Sorry about chaning your join syntax on you, it helps me organize my SQL better in my head.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error with this sql: "not a group by expression"

Comment: sorry, having clause should be: min(l2.start_date) != l1.end_date